# Could someone give me any advice on learning game engine OGRE

Tags: c++, game-engine

guys!
I am very interested in game programming.I have spent some time learning C++ and OpenGL. And now I want to learn the open source game engine **OGRE**.But I am not very clear about how to learn it.I don't have a good plan.
Does anyone have the experience of learning game programming and tell my **a good plan**?If you can recommend some good **resources about game engine OGRE such as books,webs and so on**,I will feel very appreciated for that.The more detailed,the better.Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to [ogre3d.org](http://www.ogre3d.org/) and start reading [documentation and tutorials](http://www.ogre3d.org/documentation).

Comment: @江南烟雨: Did you **click** ["documentation and tutorials" link](http://www.ogre3d.org/documentation)? [==>THIS(click me)<==](http://www.ogre3d.org/documentation) one? Well if you didn't, you should.